# Calculate sum of every pair of numbers in columns in linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I am looking for a Linux command that will sum every two rows in column 3 and 4. It will discard even numbered rows too. Thanks in advance.

Input:

```
1   10469   +   1   2
1   10470   -   1   0
1   10471   +   0   2
1   10472   -   4   0
1   10484   +   5   2
1   10485   -   0   4
```

Output:

```
1   10469   +   2   2
1   10471   +   4   2
1   10484   +   5   6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR % 2 == 1 { a=$1 OFS $2 OFS $3; b=$4; c=$5 } NR % 2 == 0 { print a, b + $4, c + $5 }' input
1 10469 + 2 2
1 10471 + 4 2
1 10484 + 5 6
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$ awk 'NR%2{split($0,p);next} {print p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4]+$4, p[5]+$5}' file
1 10469 + 2 2
1 10471 + 4 2
1 10484 + 5 6
```